# IOS App UIView not resizing on different devices

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, constraints, calayer

would appreciate some advice. I have an app with a UIView, which contains a CALayer with animation.

Using constraints, I resize the UIView for Ipad with a bigger width and height. I noticed in simulator that the correct size would not apply unless I had the appropriate device active on storyboard. I assumed this would not be an issue in production, but now the app is published, I find that if the user firstly downloads the app on the Iphone, then when they open the app on Ipad the UIView has not resized to the larger view. I assume the opposite will be true if the app is first downloaded onto the Ipad, ie., the larger UView will appear on the Iphone.

I suspect I'm making a simple mistake here, but any opinion as to where the issue might lay would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: “user firstly downloads the app on the Iphone, then when they open the app on iPad” What does this mean?

Comment: Hi, for the same Apple Id, the app is downloaded on one device, e.g., an Iphone, then on their Ipad in App Store the icon is now the cloud icon rather than GET. If they download the app firstly on the IPad using the GET icon then the view seems to size correctly.

Comment: I am not sure why the apple id would have a bearing on how the UI gets laid out unless you use the apple id somehow to check which UI to lay out ? The UI in almost all cases should be independent of your data layer and the UI should be laid out based on the device. Can you add some code if there is some logic on how you configure / set some layout especially if there are some conditions.

Comment: Turns out the issue was not the UIview not resizing correctly, but the layer not sizing to the larger UIView frame. Initialising the layer in SubViewsDidLayOut seemed to resolve the issue.